# Create file but no groups and targets?

Tags: ios, xcode

Hello I would like to add some files to group. But when I want to add this file to group, file is created outside of whole project and when I want to optimize adding the file there is no Group or Targets available. Any ideas why ?

[image: This is my groups]

[image: Create - new file]

[image: Create temp file]

[image: No groups available for adding the file to the group ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by xCode 6.3.1 at El Capitan system ...

Comment: sometimes not highlighting the group name banner will cause it to be put on the top of the file directory too. Make sure you're clicking on the group you want to add the file to before you go to create the file.